# How to serialise an integer value?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-validation

As I'm just starting working with XML serialisation.

Currently I have a class, containing an "X" attribute:

```
public class Offset
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "X")]
    public int X { get; set; }
```

XML serialisation generates something like:

```
<Offset ... X="0" .../>
              ^^^
               |
               +--- looks like a string
```

I would like the XML serialisation to look like:

```
<Offset ... X=0 ... />
              ^
              |
              +--- I'd like an integer.
```

In order to get this done, this is what I do:

```
public class Offset
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "X", DataType = "int")]
    public int X { get; set; }
```

But again this is what my serialised XML looks like:

```
<Offset ... X="0" .../>  <!-- the double quotes are still there -->
```

There are two possibilities:

- Either I'm doing something wrong and there is another way to remove those double quotes.
- Either the required XML (without double quotes) is not valid. Problem is: I've used different XML validators (XML plugin from Notepad++, saying everything is ok, and another online one, saying just the opposite), so I'm not sure.

Can anyone tell me if the required XML format is valid and in case yes, what's
the easiest way to tell the XML serialiser that an attribute must be handled as an integer (and in case of a floating point number, how to do this)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need the quotes -- `X=0` is not valid XML

Comment: The obvious test would have been deserializing, no?

Comment: Numbers can only appear without quotes when they are _within an element_ (e.g. `<ItemPrice>2.89</ItemPrice>`) **not** as an _attribute value_

Comment: I don't agree with a close reason of "Not reproducible or caused by a typo". This is a question about understanding, which has a clear yes/no answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what the OP is asking is not possible, something learnt from XML 101

Comment: Please remove my "Reopen" request: I've found a link to an official URL, which answers my question. I added it to the answer, already given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell.

Comment: @Dominique the W3Schools URL is not "official" - they're just a website, and some amount of their content is simply wrong (or outdated); you'd need to cite the xml specification for that

Comment: For the actual spec, [see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags). Follow the link to [`AttValue`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-AttValue) and you can see that attribute values are always enclosed by `"` or `'`

Comment: Separate the content and presentation! The data is for the machine, the view is for the person. Treat xml as content/data. From which it follows that it does not have to look beautiful for the eyes of a person. Therefore, let there be quotes in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that is already being generated is correct. The output you say you want: is not valid xml - attributes *must* use quotes. There is nothing to do here - the code and output is already fine, and the value is already an integer expressed as an xml attribute. This intent is valid in less strict contexts such as html, but not xml.

**Edit concerning official documentation about valid XML**

[This link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) mentions that attributes must be quoted, so `<Offset ... X=0 ... />` is not valid XML.

Comment: @Dominique while I agree with the link's conclustions: W3Schools is not exactly definitive about ... anything

Comment: Editing a moderator's answer to include additional (questionable) information... takes some courage!