# How to XML serialise a string, composed of fixed text and attribute values?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192582/how-to-serialise-an-integer-value), I asked how to XML serialise an object into something like:

```
<PO X=0 Y=0 ... />
```

My object looks as follows:

```
public class Offset
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
```

As stated in the comments and in the answer, this is invalid XML, so it makes no sense trying to XML serialise an object into that.

The customer agreed to another format (which is valid XML):

```
<PO>X=0 Y=0 ...</PO>
```

But how to do this?

I see three ways to get this done:

- Use XML serialiser instructions, like `[XmlRoot]`, `[XmlElement]`, `[XmlAttribute]` and others to steer the XML serialiser.
- Create a new attribute and use that one for the XML serialisation.
- A combination of both.

I tried the first approach but I failed, so I decided to create a new attribute, this is what I currently have:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PO")]
public class Offset
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public double X { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public double Y { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public double Z { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public double Phi { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "output")]
    public string xml_output;

    public string generate_xml_output()
    { return $"X={X} Y={Y} Z={Z} PHI={Phi}"; }

    public Offset()
    { X = 0; Y = 0; Z = 0; Phi = 0;
      xml_output = generate_xml_output(); }
```

This is my current XML:

```
<PO>
  <output>X=0 Y=0 Z=0 PHI=0</output>
</PO>
```

This is close but no cigares :-)

Does anybody know how I can tell the XML serialiser to use the `output` attribute as "default attribute" (in order to omit the `<output>` tags)?

Thanks in advance

**Edit afterwards**

At first sight, everything seems to be fine, but the `setter` is giving problems now. I've written a parser myself, but I have the impression that, although it looks good, something is missing, and messing up my XML serialisation.

This is what my class (with my implementation of the `setter`) looks like:

```
        [XmlText]
        public string xml_output
        {
            get { return $"X={X} Y={Y} Z={Z} PHI={Phi}"; }
            set { 
                  string[] temp = xml_output.Split(' ');
                  try 
                  { X = Convert.ToDouble(temp[0].Replace("X=","")); } 
                  catch (Exception) 
                  { X = 0; }
                  try
                  { Y = Convert.ToDouble(temp[1].Replace("Y=", "")); }
                  catch (Exception)
                  { Y = 0; }
                  try
                  { Z = Convert.ToDouble(temp[2].Replace("Z=", "")); }
                  catch (Exception)
                  { Z = 0; }
                  try
                  { Phi = Convert.ToDouble(temp[3].Replace("PHI=", "")); }
                  catch (Exception)
                  { Phi = 0; }
                }
        }
```

Do you know what my `setter` is missing?

Comment: Honestly, this is just a bad idea; the only *advisable* approach here would be something like `<foo X="0" Y="0" Z="0" Phi="0" />` - what is their objection to using normal regular xml here? do they like spending money for no point? this conversation should have been "an element per instance with the numeric values as attributes, exact names/capitalization to be agreed in spec to follow" (and move on to the next topic)

Comment: @MarcGravell: You're right, but this has been asked by our customers like this. Is there any way to get it done or are there any arguments to state it cannot work?

Comment: `double.TryParse(temp[0].Replace("X=", ""), out X);` do the work instead of `try-catch` block in setter.

Comment: The result of `$"X={X}"` will depend on the culture specified while the application is running. For example, the decimal separator may be a comma. And deserialization can occur on another machine with a different culture. As a result, parsing of double will break off. Therefore, either always explicitly specify the culture, or use the `XmlConvert.ToDouble`, `XmlConvert.ToString` methods.

Comment: I've solved the problem: instead of working with `xml_output` in the `setter`, I need to work with `value` (`xml_output` is not set yet at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
[XmlText]
public string CompositeOutput {
    get { return $"X={X} Y={Y} Z={Z} PHI={Phi}"; }
    set { /* your parse logic here *}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I have the impression that I'm missing something in the `setter` implementation. I've edited my question and added the `setter` implementation. Do you know what's missing?

Comment: @Dominique have you tried stepping through it with a known value and seeing what happens?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, I have. Everything seems to be working fine: the values of `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `Phi` get calculated correctly, but I have the impression that something is missing, but I can't imagine what.